# evaluating expressions in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Android studio can evalute expressions at runtime as shown from this tip. I selected overlap, than also the whole statement and while the program was running pressed option-f8. Nothing happened. Where exactly does it show to what the expression evaluated?

[image]